# Terminal.app reverse text color under cursor

Tags: macos, terminal

macOS Catalina 10.15.2, Terminal.app 2.10

In VIM:

[image: al]

and in for example VI-mode at the command line:

[image]

There is an o under the first cursor, and an s under the second cursor. In-person, I can *just about*   make out the tiniest difference, and distinguish the characters.

But it's not easy at all.

How can I make my Terminal.app invert the colors of light text when the cursor is over it?

Answer (score -1):

You can go into Preferences and change the color of your cursor so the text is visible behind it. The cursor color is changed by going to Preferences/Profiles where you get a panel like the one shown in the figure below.

[image]

I changed my cursor color to red and I could see letters behind it fine. Another option is to change your cursor to underline or a verticle bar. Those optional are selectable on the same pane to the left of my red box.

Comment: What if I cover a red letter then?

Comment: If you click on the cursor box to change the color, the color wheel comes up and you can set the opacity of whatever color you choose.  Select a color and then set the opacity to 100% and you should be able to see through the cursor.